# How should a Backbone model or collection handle views?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a collection of models, each of which is attached a view. The collection also globally has a view. Is it best for the model views to take care of deleting the corresponding model, or should the collection (or collection view) do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collections have a `.add` and `.remove` method, when you use one of them, they fire an `add` or `remove` event on the collection. This is how you can bind without using a view at all.

```js
var ships = new Backbone.Collection();
ships.bind('add', function(ship) {
  alert('Ahoy ' + ship.get('name') + '!');
});
ships.add([
  {name: 'Flying Dutchman'},
  {name: 'Black Pearl'}
]);
```

So attach the collection to the view, inside of the constructor. This simply makes the collection available via `this.collection`

```js
var ShipView = Backbone.View.extend({
  collection: ships
});
```

This is how you can bind using the view.

```js
// Create collection instance.
var ships = new Backbone.Collection();

// Create view class.
var ShipView = Backbone.View.extend({
  collection: ships,
  initialize: function() {
    // This is binding add, to the view function.
    this.collection.bind('add', this.add);
  },
  add: function(ship) {
    alert('Added ' + ship.get('name') + '!');
  }
  /*Optional for DOM.
  events: {
    'click .addMyShip': 'addShip'
  },
  addShip: function(eventObject) {
    this.collection.add([models]);
  }*/
});

// Create view instance.
var shipView = new ShipView();

// Add two ships.
ships.add([
  {name: 'Flying Dutchman'},
  {name: 'Black Pearl'}
]);
```

When the view initializes, it binds the collection's add event to run `this.add` which is a function of the view. Optionally, you can use the delegateEvents API to handle mapping DOM elements `event selector` to `function` that runs the function in the view. That function can call `this.collection.add`, of which will create the domino effect.

The way the view interacts with the collection, or model, is by binding to events, you can define those events and handle them inside the view. There are several special options that, if passed, will be available to the view: `model, collection, el, id, className, and tagName.`

Comment: so to go further on that, clicking the remove button, you could raise a remove event, picked up by the collection, the collection removes the given model (ship in this example), which triggers the remove event, the view can listen to that, and unbind it's events and remove the view from the dom.  am i missing anything?